# How should I install python packages in docker?

Tags: python, docker, pip, certificate, opc

I use python opcua to build a server in docker, and I am going to use certificate encryption and login authentication, but I am prompted with the following error when loading the certificate.

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run ()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target (* self._args, ** self._kwargs)
  File "server / opcuaserver / i3ot_opc.pyx", line 232, in server.opcuaserver.i3ot_opc.opc_server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/opcua/server/server.py", line 128, in load_certificate
    self.certificate = uacrypto.load_certificate (path)
NameError: name 'uacrypto' is not defined
```

Then I installed the cryptography command in the Jenkins file as follows.

```
pip3 install --user --trusted-host 192.168.0.200 -i http://builder:sckuangye007@192.168.0.200:8081/repository/pypi/simple coverage flake8 Cython pymodbus opcua pyzmq peewee kafka-python twisted netifaces paho-mqtt aliyun -python-sdk-core-v3 aliyun-python-sdk-ecs cryptography
```

The result are as follows.

```
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.6.1)
```

Can someone give me a suggestion? How should I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: try `from opcua.crypto import uacrypto` and see what error happens

Comment: Executing ```from opcua.crypto import uacrypto``` will cause an error, prompting ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'```.

Comment: that suggests you maybe have multiple python3 installs and pip3 is installing to a different location (try printing `sys.path`)

Comment: the path list is ```['/app', '/usr/local/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', ]```

Comment: try `python -m pip install -U ...` this will help ensure its the same python (it looks like you are using python3.7, but you installed it (and pip points at) to python3  (probably the one that came with the os)

Comment: The docker base image I used is ```FROM arm32v7 / python: 3.7-slim```, there should be no other python version.

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` is what you saw ... but your python path (and im assuming python executable is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/` which makes me quite positive you are working with 2 different python versions

Comment: I solved the problem. This installation information was installed on the compilation device during the Jenkins compilation process and was not installed in the docker image I needed. I modified the docker compilation file and installed this package in the base image. thank you very much for your help.